# Compare each line in a .txt file to a array String in Java

Tags: java, zip, checksum

```
public static boolean checkChecksum(String filePath, String checksumPath) throws Exception{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    File checksum1 = new File(checksumPath);
    try {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);     
        Enumeration e = zipFile.entries(); 
        while(e.hasMoreElements())  {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)e.nextElement(); 
            String entryName = entry.getName();
            long crc = entry.getCrc();
            String current_crc = crc+"";
    }
    zipFile.close();
    return true;
    }       
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        log.debug("Zip file may be corrupted");
        System.out.println("Error opening zip file" + ioe);
        return false;
    } 
}
```

I want to compare each line in `checksum1` file to each string value `current_crc` I get from `file.zip`.

How could I do it? And whether I have other solution to check files inside a zip file after moving from other to another PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whether I have other solution to check files inside a zip file after moving from other to another PC.

Generally we use hash checksums for checking a file's integrity - they are much more efficient and almost as reliable. Example:

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(data);
```

This code generates a small byte[] from the input byte[] (data). For checking the zip file it is enough to create a hash from the original zip and check if the copied zip's hash is the same. You can make use of the Arrays.equals() method or you can convert the byte arrays into Base64 strings for easier readability.

Fun fact: The chance of two 256-bit hashes matching is roughly equivalent of correctly guessing a 49 characters long alphanumeric password in the first try.

Comment: I want to ask a question, whether a zip file is not corrupted but the some files inside that zip file corrupt in transferring copy/paste, upload/download?

Comment: Hashing doesn't care about the layout of the data. If you have a zip file, you can read all bytes from it regardless of what 'files' it has on the inside. If you read all that data it will contain the data of all the files, so its hash will only be correct if none of the files are corrupted.